# Node empty fields behave badly when created with Entity Metadata Wrapper

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

**Problem**

Creating a node with the Entity Metadata Wrapper causes two frustrating results if select fields are left blank. (using `#empty_option` from the FAPI) .

(My form to create a node is pretty much just a more complicated version of the [create a node in code][1] example).

**Display Problem**

Typically when a node is created and a select field isn't filled in, the field will not display at all.

However when using the Entity Metadata Wrapper to create a node, if you then view the node the empty field titles still appear.

**Indexing Problem**

More frustratingly, if the node is indexed in this state it appears to store a blank string, which will appear as a blank option in a facet and throw the following error on ticking the blank facet.

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in SearchApiFacetapiTerm->addFacetFilter() (line 86 of 
/srv/www/mysite/public/sites/all/modules/search_api/contrib/search_api_facetapi/plugins/facetapi/query_type_term.inc).
```

**The Question**

Both of these problems, disappear if I edit the node and save it. So something is being called in this process, or creating a node normally that isn't called with the Entity Metadata Wrapper.

Has anyone seen this before? What could be being called in a normal node creation that's not being run with the entity metadata wrapper?

**Sample Code**

This is an extra code for a node with the select field `field_area`.

```
function createanode_form, &$form_state){

   $area_field = field_info_field('field_area');
   $area_values = list_allowed_values($area_field);

   $form['field_area'] = array(
     '#type' => 'select',
     '#title' => t('Area'),
     '#options' => $area_values,
     '#empty_option' => t("-None-"),
   );

   .....

  $form['submit'] = array(
     '#type' => 'submit',
     '#value' => t('Submit'),
     '#weight' => 70,
  );

}

function createanode_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

    $values = array(
      'type' => 'job_advert',
      'uid' => $user->uid,
      'status' => 1,
      'comment' => 1,
      'promote' => 0,
    );
    $entity = entity_create('node', $values);

    $ewrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $entity);

    $ewrapper->title->set('Test title');
    $ewrapper->body->set('A bunch of text about things that interest me');
    $ewrapper->field_area->set($form_state['values']['field_area']);

    $ewrapper->save(true);
    entity_save('node', $entity);
}
```

Comment: I could not reproduce the error described. Here is a sample script to use with `drush scr` https://gist.github.com/8825551

Comment: Hmm hold on let me provide some more sample code. It might be the error is limited to select fields.

Comment: @barraponto Ok sorry about that. Sample code added to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an `#empty_option` is defined, it will be added as a label for the empty option in a select list. The value can be defined as well, it is keyed as `#empty_value`. See the documentation for [form_process_select](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_process_select/7) for more details. You will see that for required fields, the default `#empty_value` is an empty string.

That value is filtered out in [_form_validate](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/_form_validate/7). I think it is being unset, and then when you call `$ewrapper->field_area->set()` you are actually passing `FALSE`, `NULL` or something else that PHP lovingly converts to an empty string.

I think you could solve it like this:

```
if (!empty($form_state['values']['field_area'])) {
  $ewrapper->field_area->set($form_state['values']['field_area']);
}
```

Or if you manually set the `#empty_value` to `'_EMPTY'`:

```
if ($form_state['values']['field_area'] !== '_EMPTY') {
  $ewrapper->field_area->set($form_state['values']['field_area']);
}
```

Comment: If either solution works for you, please edit my answer :D

Comment: Awesome works great. Shouldn't the second one be != though? (The problem also existed for text fields and solved it the same way.) Also is this an explanation? Default empty strings are changed to NULL by `_form_validate` this is then changed to an empty string by the Entity Wrapper. In the traditional node form the data is submitted by another method and NULL values are submitted directly, thus meaning the empty field never shows?

Comment: Yes, it should be `!==`, I'll fix it. And I think turning `FALSE` or `NULL` into an empty string is expected behavior coming from PHP.